# How to prove using definition of limit when the funtion has no specific numbers

Tags: calculus

If a is a real number and f is differentiable at a, and also f(a)>0. How would you prove that ∃ δ>0 such that if |x-a|< δ  =>  f(x)>0?

Answer (score 1):

By assumption, $m:=f'(a)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ exists. Thus for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $0<|h|<\delta$ implies $\left|\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}-m\right|<\epsilon$. Thus in this situation $m-\epsilon< \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}<m+\epsilon$. For positive $h$ this means $$\tag1f(a)+(m-\epsilon)h<f(a+h)<f(a)+(m+\epsilon)h$$ and similarly for negative $h$
$$\tag2f(a)+(m-\epsilon)h>f(a+h)>f(a)+(m+\epsilon)h.$$
Now it suffices to fix any $\epsilon>0$ (for example $\epsilon=42$) and then instead of the $\delta$ mentioned above use $$\delta':=\min\left\{\delta,\frac{f(a)}{\max\left\{|m+\epsilon|,|m-\epsilon|\right\}}\right\}$$ and verify that this works.

Alternatively, observe that the existence of $f'(a)$ impies that $f$ is *continuous* at $a$.